# How to change Row Color when Hovering over a Cell in that Row

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Is there any way in CSS the change the background-color of a Row in a table made of 3 columns, when I hover over a cell in this row?

```
table tr:hover
{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Doesn't seem to work.

**UPDATE**

I'm using Mozilla Firefox, it only works when I hover over a `<th>` not a `<td>`

Comment: That code works fine in Chrome. It may not work in older IE versions (IE7, IE8, maybe even IE9) as some of them don't register `:hover` on non-`a` elements in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax:

```
tr.hover > td:hover
{
    background-color: blue;
}

<tr class="hover">
    <td>;lajsdfl;jasdl;jasd;f</td>
    <td>;lajsdfl;jasdl;jasd;f</td>
</tr>
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DQ9Vz/

Comment: This only changes the background of 1 cell, or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @user1665700: Yep, it looks like that's what it does. Woops.

Answer (score 1):

tr:hover{
    background-color:red;
    }

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/EJ63m/

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table tr:hover
{
    background-color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td><td>FooBar</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bar</td><td>Foo</td><td>FooBar</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

What browser are you using?

Comment: @user1665700  Are you using the latest version of Firefox?  I tried the above code in Firefox 16.0.2, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved it.

```
table tr:hover > td
{
    background-color:aqua;
}
```